# Typescript conditional type that depends on type of another property

Tags: typescript

I have an `Interviewee` object that has two properties:

```
interface Interviewee {
    stageable_type: StageableType;
    stageable: IntervieweeStageable;
}
```

`StageableType` is a union type:

```
type StageableType = 'InterviewProposal' | 'Interview' | 'HireProposal' | 'Hire' | 'Failed';
```

`IntervieweeStageable` is also a union type:

```
type IntervieweeStageable = Stageable | StageableFail | StageableInterview | StageableHire;
```

if `stageable_type` = 'InterviewProposal' then `stageable` is of type `StageableInterview`

if `stageable_type` = 'Hire' then `stageable` is of type `StageableHire` etc

How can I safely use the types in code? e.g.

```
if (interviewee.stageable_type === 'Hire' && interviewee.stageable?.time) {
   ...
 }
```

Where `interviewee.stageable?.time` is an optional property that only exists on type `StageableHire`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it except unions.

Just create different sets of interfaces for each stage depending on use case and create a union type of them. [Discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) is a common technique which lets you narrow down to the possible type.

```
interface IntervieweeNonHireStage {
    stageable_type: 'InterviewProposal' | 'Interview' ,
    stageable: {
        otherKey :string 
    };
}

interface IntervieweeHireStage {
    stageable_type: 'HireProposal' | 'Hire' | 'Failed',
    stageable: { time :string};
}

type IntervieweeStage = IntervieweeHireStage | IntervieweeNonHireStage;

const x = () => {
    let interviewee1 : IntervieweeStage = {
        stageable_type: 'Hire',
    stageable: { time :'xxx'}
};
    let interviewee2 : IntervieweeStage = {
        stageable_type: 'InterviewProposal',
    stageable: { otherKey :'xxx'}
};
let arr = [interviewee1 , interviewee2 ];
 return  arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  
};
const interviewee = x();

if (interviewee.stageable_type === 'Hire' && interviewee.stageable?.time) {

 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmgN2BA7hCAOQHsQAJYKCAZTDgHMUBvAKGXeQGc7G4AjADYQA+mACeABwgAuZAHJ0kKNjwAFKMQnFOcAXOQAfeYqw5c+gDRsO3BhH5DZrDi+TEwAC2gBpCGOTS3FCg9MjW7AC+ANwsESwsoErwSGgYymYEFFS0dsjONjz2giLiUrJyWRDqmtq6+kYVlBD18gBicMBCACZyVi62vMVOyGDAALYogWDBIPTRsfGlKCbpeAQ5jMgAvKlKKvgQlRsoRiv7BCTkTccxLAik3MgAHtvIABQAlNsAfHnhyEIwMhEqY1hAAIwBXagg7HV75VxcQoOEqSGTySq9f4DIqOPIjcaTORPElyOLzFyA4Fpc4QABMULOGRohXh-36yOKojR5SZag0Wh0ej6BTsKOG7i8UF8-mkxNJ5JiVLgUCgrwA2iDVgdIRZqXtmQyALoxZBUMAAVygIHYKqg6oAsnBPAA6GACYjEKBvJ2uqBwEBdYhjT7IABUyDpHxN1liMXuIEeWtpryen1uwBg72TzJdOJR3Kk2y2O0aVH0ADIK-qYQQ85yhC7RhMvqw2BEgA)

Comment: I see what you're saying thanks.